# Jquery UI date-picker does not show up

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, datepicker

I am using [Jquery UI Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/) and [Timepicker to jQuery UI Datepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/).

I have followed the instruction in the UI documentations but my date-picker does not show at all when clicking on the input.

UI tabs and accordions works just fine and they are all called the same way.

I have put together a live test here: http://loai.directory/test/modules.php

The HTML for the date-picker is:

```
<input name="" class="date-picker" autocomplete="off" readonly="readonly">
```

All the UI elements are being called from main.js which is located in assets/js/main.js

```
//Date pickers
$("input.date-picker").datepicker({
});
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you waiting for the elements to load up? If you run that line of code in the console after the page has loaded then it appears to work fine.

Comment: Here is a direct link to main.js http://loai.directory/test/assets/js/main.js and here is a direct link to UI library: http://loai.directory/test/assets/js/jquery-ui.js

Comment: Oh, can it be the $(document).ready(function() { which the calls are wrapped up with?

Comment: Try out using jsFiddle or any other alternative so we can help you... You maybe not loading the js library or who knows..

Comment: Nothing creates them, they are hard-coded into the HTML so they load normally.

Comment: @Tsalikidis that is what baffling me, i am clearly loading the library as the UI tabs and accordions work just fine!

Comment: Oh, that is weird! I just moved '$("input.date-picker").datepicker({});' from main.js and placed it to the very bottom of jquery-ui.js and now the date-picker works! huh?

Comment: :D I can make a website using .NET and serve links with php extension! (I didn't really covered that did I?). The element seems to have an id attribute compiled by someone somehow..

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77009/discussion-on-question-by-leo-jquery-ui-date-picker-does-not-show-up).

Comment: Please check the test site again now, you will find 6 inputs, the first three are not inside a .grid system and the last three are inside .grid - the once that are not inside works fine but the ones inside a .grid does not! What does that mean?

Comment: @Leo how it got solved? all the six input fields loads up the date and timepickers correctly..

Comment: @Lucky it did not get solved, however, I found the problem! Please check out my post here: https://github.com/attila/savvior/issues/16

Comment: @Leo uhhh sorry but it seems to work fine in firefox browser..only in chrome we do have this problem i think..u working on chrome i guess..? i previously checked in chrome..

Comment: Indeed, I tried all of them, it works on Firefox but not on any of the others! It is really really weird! Any ideas?

Comment: @Leo would you be able to post your full code in a Fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

While debugging the link in the dev console I cannot see the jquery-ui.css getting loaded. I believe it contains the classes needed tgo create the calendar control. make sure the css is in the right path

[image: jquery css not loaded]

Comment: The CSS isn't the issue, as we can get the date-picker working if I moved '$("input.date-picker").datepicker({});' from main.js and placed it to the very bottom of jquery-ui.js